# Argument exception - parameter is not valid ( LinkLabel on WinForm )

Tags: c#, forms, gdi+, linklabel, argumentexception

I wrote a Win Forms app to test how a LinkLabel class works.  It appears to be fine until I click on the changed LinkLabel.  The Form1.cs code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace LinkLabelTest
{
// Editor: code not fully indented - laziness!
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {  
            InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnLinkColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        colorDialog1.ShowDialog();
        llblinkLabel1.LinkColor = colorDialog1.Color;
    }

    private void btnActiveLinkColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        colorDialog1.ShowDialog();
        llblinkLabel1.ActiveLinkColor = colorDialog1.Color;
    }

    private void btnVisitedLinkColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        colorDialog1.ShowDialog();
        llblinkLabel1.VisitedLinkColor = colorDialog1.Color;
    }

    private void llblinkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            if (!(e.Link.Description == null))
            {
                if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
                {
                    PopulateLinkDetails(e.Link);
                }

                if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
                {   
                    e.Link.Visited = true;
                    Debugger.Break();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Debugger.Break();
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message.ToString());
        }   
    }

    private void PopulateLinkDetails(LinkLabel.Link link)
    {
        textDescription.Text = link.Description;
        textLinkData.Text = (string)link.LinkData;
        textName.Text = link.Name;
        checkBoxEnabled.Checked = link.Enabled;
        checkBoxVisited.Checked = link.Visited;
        nudLinkAreaStart.Value = link.Start;
        nudLinkAreaEnd.Value = link.Length;
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            cmbLinkBehaviour.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(LinkBehavior));
    }

    private void cmbLinkBehaviour_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        llblinkLabel1.LinkBehavior = (LinkBehavior)cmbLinkBehaviour.SelectedItem;
    }

    private void AddLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            LinkLabel.Link link = new LinkLabel.Link();

            link.Description = textDescription.Text.ToString();
            link.LinkData = textLinkData.Text.ToString();
            link.Name = textName.Text.ToString();
            link.Enabled = checkBoxEnabled.Checked;
            link.Visited = checkBoxVisited.Checked;
            link.Start = (int)nudLinkAreaStart.Value;
            link.Length = (int)nudLinkAreaEnd.Value;

            llblinkLabel1.Links.Add(link);
    }

}
}
```

The stack trace is below :

> at System.Drawing.Region.GetHrgn(Graphics g) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invalidate(Region region, Boolean
>   invalidateChildren) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.InvalidateLink(Link link) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.OnGotFocus(EventArgs e) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmSetFocus(Message& m) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Label.WndProc(Message& m) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.WndProc(Message& msg) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m) at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SetFocus(HandleRef hWnd) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.FocusInternal() at
>   System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseDown(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks) at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&
>   m) at System.Windows.Forms.Label.WndProc(Message& m) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.WndProc(Message& msg) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m) at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm) at
>   LinkLabelTest.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Tony\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\LinkLabelTest\LinkLabelTest\Program.cs:line 22

Below is the designer generated code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace LinkLabelTest
{
// Editor: code not fully indented - laziness again!
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {

        this.llblinkLabel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel();
        this.colorDialog1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ColorDialog();
        this.btnLinkColor = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.btnActiveLinkColor = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.btnVisitedLinkColor = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.nudLinkAreaStart = new System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown();
        this.lbllabel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.nudLinkAreaEnd = new System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown();
        this.lbllabel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.cmbLinkBehaviour = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.lbllabel3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.groupBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.textDescription = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.textName = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.textLinkData = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.label4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.checkBoxEnabled = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
        this.AddLink = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.btnAmendLink = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.checkBoxVisited = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
        this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.nudLinkAreaStart)).BeginInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.nudLinkAreaEnd)).BeginInit();
        this.groupBox1.SuspendLayout();
        this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // llblinkLabel1
        // 
        this.llblinkLabel1.AutoSize = true;
        this.llblinkLabel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 27);
        this.llblinkLabel1.Name = "llblinkLabel1";
        this.llblinkLabel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(96, 13);
        this.llblinkLabel1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.llblinkLabel1.TabStop = true;
        this.llblinkLabel1.Text = "This is a link label !";
        this.llblinkLabel1.LinkClicked += new System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(this.llblinkLabel1_LinkClicked);
        // 
        // btnLinkColor
        // 
        this.btnLinkColor.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 19);
        this.btnLinkColor.Name = "btnLinkColor";
        this.btnLinkColor.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(93, 23);
        this.btnLinkColor.TabIndex = 2;
        this.btnLinkColor.Text = "LinkColor";
        this.btnLinkColor.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.btnLinkColor.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnLinkColor_Click);
        // 
        // btnActiveLinkColor
        // 
        this.btnActiveLinkColor.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 48);
        this.btnActiveLinkColor.Name = "btnActiveLinkColor";
        this.btnActiveLinkColor.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(93, 23);
        this.btnActiveLinkColor.TabIndex = 3;
        this.btnActiveLinkColor.Text = "ActiveLinkColor";
        this.btnActiveLinkColor.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.btnActiveLinkColor.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnActiveLinkColor_Click);
        // 
        // btnVisitedLinkColor
        // 
        this.btnVisitedLinkColor.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 77);
        this.btnVisitedLinkColor.Name = "btnVisitedLinkColor";
        this.btnVisitedLinkColor.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(93, 23);
        this.btnVisitedLinkColor.TabIndex = 4;
        this.btnVisitedLinkColor.Text = "VisitedLinkColor";
        this.btnVisitedLinkColor.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.btnVisitedLinkColor.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnVisitedLinkColor_Click);
        // 
        // nudLinkAreaStart
        // 
        this.nudLinkAreaStart.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(152, 64);
        this.nudLinkAreaStart.Maximum = new decimal(new int[] {
        21,
        0,
        0,
        0});
        this.nudLinkAreaStart.Name = "nudLinkAreaStart";
        this.nudLinkAreaStart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(66, 20);
        this.nudLinkAreaStart.TabIndex = 6;
        // 
        // lbllabel1
        // 
        this.lbllabel1.AutoSize = true;
        this.lbllabel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(224, 71);
        this.lbllabel1.Name = "lbllabel1";
        this.lbllabel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(74, 13);
        this.lbllabel1.TabIndex = 7;
        this.lbllabel1.Text = "Link area start";
        // 
        // nudLinkAreaEnd
        // 
        this.nudLinkAreaEnd.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(152, 99);
        this.nudLinkAreaEnd.Maximum = new decimal(new int[] {
        21,
        0,
        0,
        0});
        this.nudLinkAreaEnd.Name = "nudLinkAreaEnd";
        this.nudLinkAreaEnd.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(67, 20);
        this.nudLinkAreaEnd.TabIndex = 8;
        // 
        // lbllabel2
        // 
        this.lbllabel2.AutoSize = true;
        this.lbllabel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(224, 105);
        this.lbllabel2.Name = "lbllabel2";
        this.lbllabel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(83, 13);
        this.lbllabel2.TabIndex = 9;
        this.lbllabel2.Text = "Link area length";
        // 
        // cmbLinkBehaviour
        // 
        this.cmbLinkBehaviour.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.cmbLinkBehaviour.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 106);
        this.cmbLinkBehaviour.Name = "cmbLinkBehaviour";
        this.cmbLinkBehaviour.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(93, 21);
        this.cmbLinkBehaviour.TabIndex = 10;
        this.cmbLinkBehaviour.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cmbLinkBehaviour_SelectedIndexChanged);
        // 
        // lbllabel3
        // 
        this.lbllabel3.AutoSize = true;
        this.lbllabel3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(-3, 130);
        this.lbllabel3.Name = "lbllabel3";
        this.lbllabel3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(78, 13);
        this.lbllabel3.TabIndex = 11;
        this.lbllabel3.Text = "Link Behaviour";
        // 
        // groupBox1
        // 
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.btnLinkColor);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.btnActiveLinkColor);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.lbllabel3);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.btnVisitedLinkColor);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.cmbLinkBehaviour);
        this.groupBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 57);
        this.groupBox1.Name = "groupBox1";
        this.groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(124, 155);
        this.groupBox1.TabIndex = 13;
        this.groupBox1.TabStop = false;
        this.groupBox1.Text = "THE link label";
        // 
        // textDescription
        // 
        this.textDescription.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(152, 136);
        this.textDescription.Name = "textDescription";
        this.textDescription.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
        this.textDescription.TabIndex = 14;
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(259, 143);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(60, 13);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 15;
        this.label1.Text = "Description";
        // 
        // textName
        // 
        this.textName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(152, 163);
        this.textName.Name = "textName";
        this.textName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
        this.textName.TabIndex = 16;
        // 
        // label2
        // 
        this.label2.AutoSize = true;
        this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(262, 170);
        this.label2.Name = "label2";
        this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        this.label2.TabIndex = 17;
        this.label2.Text = "Name";
        // 
        // label3
        // 
        this.label3.AutoSize = true;
        this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 11);
        this.label3.Name = "label3";
        this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(283, 13);
        this.label3.TabIndex = 18;
        this.label3.Text = "Right Click on a link to retrieve properties. Left Click to visit";
        // 
        // textLinkData
        // 
        this.textLinkData.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(152, 191);
        this.textLinkData.Name = "textLinkData";
        this.textLinkData.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
        this.textLinkData.TabIndex = 19;
        // 
        // label4
        // 
        this.label4.AutoSize = true;

        this.label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(262, 198);
        this.label4.Name = "label4";
        this.label4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(53, 13);
        this.label4.TabIndex = 20;
        this.label4.Text = "Link Data";
        // 
        // checkBoxEnabled
        // 
        this.checkBoxEnabled.AutoSize = true;
        this.checkBoxEnabled.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(151, 218);
        this.checkBoxEnabled.Name = "checkBoxEnabled";
        this.checkBoxEnabled.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(65, 17);
        this.checkBoxEnabled.TabIndex = 21;
        this.checkBoxEnabled.Text = "Enabled";
        this.checkBoxEnabled.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // AddLink
        // 
        this.AddLink.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(385, 64);
        this.AddLink.Name = "AddLink";
        this.AddLink.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.AddLink.TabIndex = 22;
        this.AddLink.Text = "Add Link";
        this.AddLink.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.AddLink.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.AddLink_Click);
        // 
        // btnAmendLink
        // 
        this.btnAmendLink.Enabled = false;
        this.btnAmendLink.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(385, 99);
        this.btnAmendLink.Name = "btnAmendLink";
        this.btnAmendLink.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.btnAmendLink.TabIndex = 23;
        this.btnAmendLink.Text = "AmendLink";
        this.btnAmendLink.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // checkBoxVisited
        // 
        this.checkBoxVisited.AutoSize = true;
        this.checkBoxVisited.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(151, 241);
        this.checkBoxVisited.Name = "checkBoxVisited";
        this.checkBoxVisited.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(57, 17);
        this.checkBoxVisited.TabIndex = 24;
        this.checkBoxVisited.Text = "Visited";
        this.checkBoxVisited.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // panel1
        // 
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
        this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(474, 13);
        this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
        this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 239);
        this.panel1.TabIndex = 25;
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this.textBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.textBox1.Multiline = true;
        this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 239);
        this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(704, 264);
        this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.checkBoxVisited);
        this.Controls.Add(this.btnAmendLink);
        this.Controls.Add(this.AddLink);
        this.Controls.Add(this.checkBoxEnabled);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label4);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textLinkData);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label3);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textName);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textDescription);
        this.Controls.Add(this.groupBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.lbllabel2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.nudLinkAreaEnd);
        this.Controls.Add(this.lbllabel1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.nudLinkAreaStart);
        this.Controls.Add(this.llblinkLabel1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.nudLinkAreaStart)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.nudLinkAreaEnd)).EndInit();
        this.groupBox1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.groupBox1.PerformLayout();
        this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.panel1.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel llblinkLabel1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ColorDialog colorDialog1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnLinkColor;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnActiveLinkColor;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnVisitedLinkColor;
    private System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown nudLinkAreaStart;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label lbllabel1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown nudLinkAreaEnd;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label lbllabel2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox cmbLinkBehaviour;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label lbllabel3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textDescription;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textName;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textLinkData;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label4;
    private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox checkBoxEnabled;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button AddLink;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnAmendLink;
    private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox checkBoxVisited;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
}
}
```

Please can someone advise.  Is the problem that there is no windows handle for the LinkLabel when its Paint event occurs.

Many thanks in advance

Tony

Comment: OMG please post relevant code and errors only! This is just too much, there is no problem that is *that* complicated.

Comment: @Tomalak: there are problems that are *that* complicated; however, I agree that this probably isn't one of them.

Comment: I know. This was a rhetoric exaggeration. ;-) @Tony: Edit your question, make the *shortest possible* program that solely demonstrates the problem (e.g. max. 20 lines of code), format it nicely and you'll have an answer really soon. Removing your own answer will also help, but only after your edit.

Answer (score 1):

The following sample code shows how you can set a link label's color from a `ColorDialog`:

```
using (var colorDlg = new ColorDialog())
{
    if (colorDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       llblinkLabel1.LinkColor = colorDlg.Color;
    }
}
```

Comment: I expanded your code example by adding a `using` block: `ColorDialog` is `IDisposable`, so you should make sure that it is disposed of properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void AddLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // do proper validation and add only proper links
        // this will help you to avoid the exception 
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textLinkData.Text) && 
            nudLinkAreaEnd.Value > 0 && 
            nudLinkAreaStart.Value >= 0 && 
            nudLinkAreaStart.Value < llblinkLabel1.Text.Length)
       {
           LinkLabel.Link link = new LinkLabel.Link();
           link.Description = textDescription.Text.ToString();
           link.LinkData = textLinkData.Text.ToString();
           link.Name = textName.Text.ToString();
           link.Enabled = checkBoxEnabled.Checked;
           link.Visited = checkBoxVisited.Checked;
           link.Start = (int)nudLinkAreaStart.Value;
           link.Length = (int)nudLinkAreaEnd.Value;
           try
           {
               llblinkLabel1.Links.Add(link); 
           }
           catch (InvalidOperationException exception) // links can't overlap 
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Links are overlaping");
           }

       }
```